# explain the trigger how it works

Tags: trigger

```
trigger BeforeinsertTrigger on Account (before insert) {

    for(schema.Account acc:Trigger.new){
        if(acc.Type =='propect' && acc.Industry=='Healthcare'){
            acc =[select id,Name,AccountNumber,Site from Account];



           }
         System.debug(''+acc);


    }

}
```

Comment: You've been pointed to [How to ask a good question](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/how-to-ask) twice before now (this being the third time), and I still don't know if you've actually read it. I can't speak for others, but my patience is wearing thin. I strongly advise you to do some research before asking questions, and include more details. In this case, including your current thoughts as to what the trigger is doing would help.

Comment: What part of the code or trigger concept is unclear to you ? Have you already read any documentation on triggers or apex ? Without having more details it is extremely hard for us to know how deep and broad we need to answer that and whether that's even possible or not. Please provide more info by updating the question,

Answer (score 3):

When a new account is inserted, and its Type is "Prospect", and its Industry is "Healthcare", and there is not exactly one account in the database, the trigger crashes with a QueryException of either "no rows for assignment", "too many rows for assignment", or "too many query rows", depending on the state of the database at the time the record is being inserted. In other words, this code does nothing useful at best, and will cause continuous crashes in production, effectively preventing any accounts matching that criteria from being inserted.